# How to get the details of first listitem in Listview?

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview, I used custom adapter for it. Each list item has three textviews.

My requirement is that, I have to get the text from first list item.

I tried the following code, but not working

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.contactList);
listView.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(ContactListActivity.this, contactList));
Contact contact = (Contact)listView.getItemAtPosition(0);
String firstName = contact.getDisplayName();
```

contactList is the arraylist of custom object Contact, which has 3 fields name, phone & email.

my adapter code

class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private List contactList;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

```
public CustomAdapter(Context context, List<Contact> contactList2) {
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.contactList = contactList2;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return contactList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return contactList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    viewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contactlistitem, null);
        holder = new viewHolder();
        holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtDisplayName);
        holder.number = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtPhone);
        holder.email = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtMailID);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (viewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.name.setText(contactList.get(position).getDisplayName());
    holder.number.setText(contactList.get(position).getPhone());
    holder.email.setText(contactList.get(position).getEmail());

    return convertView;
}

public class viewHolder {
    TextView name;
    TextView number;
    TextView email;
}
```

}

What is my mistake, any suggestions?

Comment: It should work. Is there any error you are getting?

Comment: Your CustomAdapter must contain code to find the 3 text views in the list item. i.e. `findViewById` must be used in the CustomAdapter. You must override the `getView` or one of the other (new|bind)view calls.

Comment: Its crashing... java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer

Comment: Show us the adapter code.

Comment: is contactList is type of Array or ArrayList

Comment: contactList is ArrayList

Comment: @Anilkumar posted my answer do like that..

Comment: @kalyanpvs - Ya its good, but problem is I wont the same list every time... I will use some dynamic lists also... So I want to retrieve from listview rather than lists

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Contact contact = (Contact) listView.getAdapter().getItem(position);
String firstName = contact.getDisplayName();
```

Comment: Its crashing... java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer

Comment: I find no mistake in your initial code. what exception you are getting. If you can post your adapter code, it will be easy to help you

Answer (score 1):

Why you need to get The First item from the `ListView` or `Adapter`.You have Already `ArrayList` data just get Like this..

```
Contact contact = contactList.get(0);
String firstName = contact.getDisplayName();
```

based on OP requirement
change like this..

```
    CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(ContactListActivity.this, contactList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    Contact contact = (Contact)adapter.getItem(0);
    String firstName = contact.getDisplayName();
```

Comment: Ya its good, but problem is I wont the same list every time... I will use some dynamic lists also... So I want to retrieve from listview rather than lists